# Google Map Search with City/state or Zip

Tags: php, api, google-maps

i would like to make a search with city/state or Zip within a 'X' distance . The corresponding results will be viewed in google map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html) article.

> This tutorial is intended for
>   developers who are familiar with
>   PHP/MySQL, and want to learn how to
>   use Google Maps with a MySQL database
>   to create a store locator-type app.
>   After completing this tutorial, you
>   will have a database of locations and
>   a webpage that lets a user enter their
>   address and see markers on a map for
>   the locations nearest to them, within
>   a chosen distance restriction.

Comment: @stukelly

Thanks for this help :)

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps' rich API is thoroughly documented at links starting from http://code.google.com/apis/maps/ .